# What's the easiest way to upgrade Ghostscript?

Tags: upgrade, ghostscript

I have version 8 of Ghostscript on my Ubuntu 10.04 server.

What is the easiest way to install version 9?  Source install?  PPA?  Something else?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to upgrade to ghostscript 9.15 or more, follow this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/675710/306960.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ghostscript is not found under **Ubuntu Software Center**

So, either install it from there or you can just update your current version to latest one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

If that doesn't work download one of the following:

- [64 bit](http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.05~dfsg-6.1_amd64.deb)
- [32bit](http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.05~dfsg-6.1_i386.deb)

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path-to-downloadedpackage.deb
```

Comment: That just install version 8 of gs, which I already have.

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: links are dead...

Comment: @n3rd You can download the .deb file here. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript

Answer (score 11):

### default version

The recommended way is (as posted before):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

### Ghostscript 10.02 via terminal

If you need a **newer version** than provided by your Ubuntu-Version:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/prgm
cd ~/prgm
wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10021/ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz
tar xvf ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz
cd ghostscript-10.02.1/
sudo ./configure
sudo make install
#restart Terminal
gs -v
ghostscript -v
```

### current Ghostscript manually

- Download "*Ghostscript 10 Source*" from [https://ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) (direct link to [gs 10.02.1](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10021/ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz))
- uncompress it (f.e. `tar xvf ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz`)
- go into this folder
- `sudo ./configure`
- `sudo make install`
- restart Terminal
- Test with `gs -v`

To check your version (maybe after restarting terminal)

```
ghostscript -v
```