# Update Ghostscript on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, ghostscript

First of all, I am well aware of this question: [What's the easiest way to upgrade Ghostscript?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199489/whats-the-easiest-way-to-upgrade-ghostscript).

Unfortunately none of the answers worked. I *can* find `deb` files from [this list](https://pkgs.org/download/ghostscript). There, I am surprised to see that the last version of Ghostscript for Ubuntu 14.04 is version 9.10. When I download version 9.15 for Ubuntu 15.04, and I run it (as root), I get the error:

> Error: dependency is not satisfiable **libgs9**

I checked (`apt-get install libgs9`) and I have the latest libgs9 installed. Also, [this site](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/ghostscript) seems to confirm that last is version 9.10 for 14.04.

Does this mean it is not possible to upgrade Ghostscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you want to do is not possible. At least not without making your system broken.

You can't install the Vivid version of `ghostscript` in Trusty. The package has some dependencies and one of them is `libgs9 (= 9.15+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1)`. The version for `libgs9` in Trusty is `libgs9 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.4)`. Therefore, forget it. **:)**

Repair your system via

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

In the meantime you could try this PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ghostscript
```

Comment: So sad... That means I can't use [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) properly!!

Comment: If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** at the left-hand side of my answer, now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask **;)**

Comment: You could install Vivid

Comment: I like your answer so I upvoted. But I am still waiting for other possible answer. If no better (= allowing me to upgrade only ghostscript) answer come, I will accept it!

Comment: Understand. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Wow excellent!! That works! Can you explain how you managed to find this out? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, Google and "ghostscript 9.15 Trusty"