# gs: /MATLAB/ /bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libgs.so.9)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, matlab, ghostscript

When I use in Matlab

```
!epstopdf "output.eps" --outfile=output.pdf
```

then I get one of the following message:

```
gs: /opt/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available  (required by /usr/lib/libgs.so.9)
gs: /opt/sw/x86_64/generic/Matlab/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libgs.so.9)
gs: /opt/sw/x86_64/generic/Matlab/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libgs.so.9)
```

I am using Ghostscript 9.18 (default version of Ubuntu 16.04). (Same Problem with Ghostscript 9.07)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no version information available means that you have an old version (of Ghostscript) see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/156387/6747994

Therefore you have to update to Ghostscript 9.23 (or newer):
https://askubuntu.com/a/942995/676490

You have to

- Download the source code from https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html or https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases (direct link to [gs 10.02.1](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10021/ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz))
- uncompress it (f.e. `tar xvf ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz`)
- go into this folder
- `sudo ./configure`
- `sudo make install`
- restart Terminal
- Test with `gs -v` which Version you have

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Linux Mint 21 Vanessa 64-bit), the problem lies in the incompatibility of the libraries libtiff.so.5 and libstdc++.so.6 installed with the system and those shipped with Matlab.

System:

- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.7.0`

shipped with the Matlab distribution:

- `R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` is a symlink to `R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28`
- `R2022b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5` is a symlink to `R2022b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5.8.0`

To overcome this problem, you need to ensure that the relevant symlinks in the Matlab's library folders point to the system library files rather than those shipped with Matlab. That is:

- `R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` must be a symlink to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30`
- `R2022b/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5` must be a symlink to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.7.0`

This has been an issue for many years, and the above approach always worked. For a particular version of Matlab and your system, you simply need to use the Matlab folder and system libraries that are appropriate for your system (in the above example: R2022b and whatever versions are in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, when does the error occur?

Comment: For me, it happens whenever I install a new version of Matlab. Matlab distribution comes with its own versions of `libtiff.so` and `libstdc++.so`, but these are typically different from those on the linux system. For some reason, they clash with each other, for example, when I want to make a call to `epstopdf` within Matlab (to convert `eps` files produced in Matlab to `pdf` files).

Answer (score 0):

When I use the mex command to compile opencv c++ files or when I use mex files, i get an similar error message like this:

MATLAB/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: version `LIBTIFF_4.0' not found (required by *)

or

"Invalid MEX-file '.mexa64': libtiff.so.5: version 'LIBTIFF_4.0' not found"(required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4)

I solved it in the following way, please refer to.

```bash
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5
```

The first line of the command removes the `libtiff.xo.5` file from its original path. The second command is to link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4` to `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5`. This way the two file versions correspond and the problem is solved.

Execute the command `locate libtiff.so.5.2.4`
You will find this file in the `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/` directory.
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.4`

Note that the matlab version path above should be the one belonging to you.