# How to install newer version of ghostscript on server than provided from ubuntu?

Tags: ghostscript

I need to upgrade my ghostscript version from 9.22 to 9.25 on my server. I am running a laravel forge droplet on digital ocean.

I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

In accordance to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199489/whats-the-easiest-way-to-upgrade-ghostscript?newreg=9e67d280214b4c7ca5e500fe10a7d8fc).

However as this second answer there indicates you might want a newer version than what this gives you. In my case, I get 9.22 doing it that way but I need 9.25. So how do I go about to install the newer version on the server only using the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/942995/676490) it is not only explained the easiest way to install ghostscript (as asked), but also the way how to derive newer versions of ghotscript.

If you want the newest Ghostscript:

- Download "*Ghostscript Source*" from https://ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html or ghostscript-10.tar.gz from [Github](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/) (direct link to [gs 10.02.1](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10021/ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz))
- uncompress it: (f.e. `tar -xvf ghostscript-10.02.1.tar.gz`)
- go into this folder
- `sudo ./configure`
- `sudo make install`
- restart Terminal
- Test with `gs -v`

To check your version (maybe after restarting terminal)

```
ghostscript -v
```